# Accessing mangled member of another instance

Tags: python, oop, code-analysis, pylint, private-members

I use this logic to maintain a directed tree of `Object` instances :

```
class Object:
    def __init__(self, *parents: 'Object'):
        self.__parents = list(parents)

    @property
    def __ascendants(self):
        for parent in self.__parents:
            yield from parent.__ascendants
            yield parent
```

This code runs fine, but PyLint is complaining about `__ascendants` being a protected member of `parent`, which is, to PyLint, a client class.

In the case of a protected, non-mangled, member, that would be fine : I should not access such members as they could be overriden by an `Object` subclass.

But in this case, as the attributes are mangled, it's not possible for a subclass to override them, which is why I allow myself to use them even on external objects (provided to the constructor).

**TLDR** ; I'm looking for a way to make PyLint accept accessing mangled attributes of a client subclass, without having to resort to `#pylint: disable=protected-access` each time, or disabling the warning globally.

It looks like I can use the `astng` callback to register a `MANAGER`, and transform a module so that PyLint can use additional information. However, I was only able to add stub members (so that dynamically added members can be used without warnings), and I'm not really sure that I can solve my problem this way.

I also tried to add `assert isinstance(parent, Object)`, but it won't help.

**EDIT** :

I was able to write the code so that PyLInt doesn't raise `protected-access`, but only to raise `bad-staticmethod-argument`. I don't use other staticmethod s in this particular class, so maybe this can be an acceptable answer to this problem :

```
class Object:
    def __init__(self, *parents: 'Object'):
        self.__parents = list(parents)

    @staticmethod
    def __get_ascendants(self: 'Object'):
        for parent in self.__parents:
            yield from self.__get_ascendants(parent)
            yield parent
```

**EDIT 2** : (inspired by @shx2)

Using a lambda with the correct argument name also fools Pylint:

```
class Object:
    def __init__(self, *parents: 'Object'):
        self.__parents = list(parents)

    @property
    def __ascendants(self):
        get_ascendants = lambda self: self.__ascendants

        for parent in self.__parents:
            yield from get_ascendants(parent)
            yield parent
```

**EDIT 3** : Because names do not leak out of generator expressions (or list omprehensions), it can also be written this way :

```
from itertools import chain

class Object:
    def __init__(self, *parents: 'Object'):
        self.__parents = list(parents)

    @property
    def __ascendants(self):
        return chain(*(
           chain(self.__ascendants, (self, ))
           for self in self.__parents
        ))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm looking for a way to make PyLint accept accessing mangled attributes of a client subclass

There are ways to fool pylint.

One way is to disguise `parent` as `self`:

```
@property
def __ascendants(self):
    for parent in self.__parents:
        self = parent
        yield from self.__ascendants
        yield self
```

Another is accessing the attribute indirectly, using `getattr`.  Instead of:

```
yield from parent.__ascendants
```

do:

```
yield from getattr(parent, '__ascendants')
```

Comment: That would be equivalent to  `# pylint: disable=protected-access`, with the added inconvenient that it wouldn't check for non-existing members.

Comment: Ah, yes that works too ! I had actually edited my post showing another way  I found with a dedicated  `staticmethod` that takes `self` (which is similar in essence to your answer). I'm not sure which one  is the most readable and/or least hackish. What do you think ?

Comment: Well, both are somewhat hacky. IMO the one assigning to `self` is better because it only deals with variable names, and only in one place. The rational is simple: pylint cares about names, so we change the name to fool it.  The one using a `staticmethod` involves more changes in more places (change function's signature, change the way it is called), and is harder to decipher what it achieves.

Comment: I did not find any way to use other attributes on `self` (the real one) after rebinding it. If I alias it to another name, pylint raises `protected-access` again, unless I alias it to a name like `cls`, but that would be really hacky and misleading. The only way I can think of is gathering all required methods from `self` before rebinding it, but then that wouldn't work for descriptors.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you making the `ascendants` method a mangled property? If you really want to use such a complicated inheritance and keep multiple `parents` attribute for each of superclasses, mangling `parents` will work. However, it seems like there is no use in mangling `ascendants` function because it belongs to the class, not to the object itself:

```
class Object(object):
    def __init__(self, parents):
        self.__parents = list(parents)

    def ascendants(self):
        for parent in self.__parents:
            yield from parent.ascendants()
            yield parent
```

Comment: I only need to keep a single `parents` attribute, on `Object`., not on each subclass. Subclasses don't need access to parents, ascendants and children. This property is purely internal to this class and doesn't need to (shouldn't) be part of the public API, as it will by only be used by other methods defined on `Object`. I don't want subclasses to be able to override `ascendants`, which wouldn't be very useful to them as they don't have access to `_Object__parents`.